My systemd service stopped working after updating server jarfile
I have a fabric minecraft server running on Oracle Linux, which I updated today, but now Java exits with status code 1 and says that  server.jar can't be found.
Please help me, I really don't understand why it does this and it's frustrating.
Here's my service file:
[Unit]
Description=Minecraft server
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/opc/minecraft/
ExecStart=java -Xmx6144M -Xms6144M -jar server.jar nogui
User=opc
Group=opc
StandardOutput=journal
Restart=on-failure
TimeoutStopSec=180
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Here are the files in the WorkingDirectory:
[opc@minecraft minecraft]$ ls
banned-ips.json  banned-players.json  config  eula.txt  fabricloader.log  libraries  logs  mods  ops.json  server.jar  server.properties  usercache.json  versions  whitelist.json  world

Their security context:
[opc@minecraft minecraft]$ ls -Z
unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 banned-ips.json          system_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 fabricloader.log  unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 ops.json           unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 versions
unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 banned-players.json  unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 libraries         unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 server.jar         unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 whitelist.json
unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 config               unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 logs              unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 server.properties  unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 world
unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 eula.txt             unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 mods              unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 usercache.json

And the log:
May 20 18:44:02 minecraft systemd[1]: Started Minecraft server.
-- Subject: Unit minecraft.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://support.oracle.com
-- 
-- Unit minecraft.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
May 20 18:44:02 minecraft java[14047]: Error: Unable to access jarfile fabric-server-mc.1.20.6-loader.0.15.11-launcher.1.0.1.jar
May 20 18:44:02 minecraft systemd[1]: minecraft.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 20 18:44:02 minecraft systemd[1]: minecraft.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://support.oracle.com
-- 
-- The unit minecraft.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.

(yes I tried rebooting)
Also when I execute the command myself it works fine so I really don't know.
Thanks for helping!

The title says you changed a file. What file and how?

Can you post the exact output you get rather than just paraphrasing it?

And, rather than doing ls twice, just post the output of ls -lZ.  Or, better yet, ls -alZ.

I've generally used the absolute path within the systemd file  - e.g. try:
ExecStart=java -Xmx6144M -Xms6144M -jar /home/opc/minecraft/server.jar nogui

if you wanted to set the path use RootDir - but using absolute path as I mentioned above should work.

Using the absolute path nor setting RootDir work for some reason, but atleast it narrows down the issue to Java.
Also I edited the original post to include the actual log instead of paraphrasing it.
